# Can I change the name of a generated FooReference property?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

I have a table with these columns

- FooId (FK, int, not null)
- FooReference (nvarchar, null)

Pulling this table into a database-first model generates an error:

> The NavigationProperty 'Foo' on the type 'Bar.Baz' is the source of a generated property 'FooReference' which conflicts with a member of the same name.

From what I understand, the navigation property causes a `FooReference` property to be generated. Is there a way to change the name of that property, or will I have to modify the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just rename FooReference to FooReference1 (or whatever you like) in the generated edmx model

[image]